# postfix TLS disconnect from unknown

Tags: postfix, tls, sasl

I install centos 6.4 posttfix with sasl and TLS
my postconf -e

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = itzena.cz
myhostname = server.itzena.cz
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,    permit_sasl_authenticated,    reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
[root@server postfix]# cat /etc/postfix/master.cf
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628      inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o smtp_fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# The Cyrus deliver program has changed incompatibly, multiple times.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
#uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
#ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
#
#bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
#
#scalemail-backend unix -       n       n       -       2       pipe
#  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store
#  ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
#
#mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
#  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

telnet localhost 25

```
[root@server postfix]# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 server.itzena.cz ESMTP Postfix
ehlo localhost
250-server.itzena.cz
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

seems TLS and SASL is configured

now I try to connect to mail server from my PC with thundebird, but in /var/log/maillog i see

```
Jul 11 21:12:17 server postfix/smtpd[2444]: connect from unknown[88.146.132.31]
Jul 11 21:12:17 server postfix/smtpd[2441]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from unknown[88.146.132.31]
Jul 11 21:12:17 server postfix/smtpd[2441]: disconnect from unknown[88.146.132.31]
Jul 11 21:12:17 server postfix/smtpd[2444]: improper command pipelining after EHLO from unknown[88.146.132.31]
Jul 11 21:12:17 server postfix/smtpd[2444]: disconnect from unknown[88.146.132.31]
```

in thunderbird I cannot connet to mail server to send email

```
 swaks -s localhost --to mardon@itzena.cz --from postmaster@itzena.cz -tls -p 25
=== Trying localhost:25...
=== Connected to localhost.
<-  220 server.itzena.cz ESMTP Postfix
 -> EHLO server.itzena.cz
<-  250-server.itzena.cz
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 10240000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-STARTTLS
<-  250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
<-  250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250 DSN
 -> STARTTLS
<-  220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
=== TLS started w/ cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
=== TLS peer subject DN="/C=cz/L=valmez/O=itzena/OU=admin/CN=server.itzena.cz/emailAddress=admin@itzena.cz"
 ~> EHLO server.itzena.cz
<~  250-server.itzena.cz
<~  250-PIPELINING
<~  250-SIZE 10240000
<~  250-VRFY
<~  250-ETRN
<~  250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
<~  250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
<~  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<~  250-8BITMIME
<~  250 DSN
 ~> MAIL FROM:<postmaster@itzena.cz>
<~  250 2.1.0 Ok
 ~> RCPT TO:<mardon@itzena.cz>
<~  250 2.1.5 Ok
 ~> DATA
<~  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 ~> Date: Fri, 12 Jul 2013 06:35:27 +0200
 ~> To: mardon@itzena.cz
 ~> From: postmaster@itzena.cz
 ~> Subject: test Fri, 12 Jul 2013 06:35:27 +0200
 ~> X-Mailer: swaks v20111230.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 ~>
 ~> This is a test mailing
 ~>
 ~> .
<~  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 7A820184A
 ~> QUIT
```

in thunderbird automatic connection is nothing detetct, than I manual settings but nothing is function

Comment: Could you show output of the following command # swaks -s localhost --to user1@itzena.cz --from postmaster@itzena.cz -tls -p 25 You can install swaks from EPEL

Comment: What is your Thunderbird configuration? (port number, TLS/StartTLS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in master.cf I uncomment

```
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

on iptables allow port 465 and now is function

Postfix over SSL is not using port 25?

Comment: "Postfix over SSL is not using port 25?" No, Port 25 is reserved for SMTP and additionally STARTTLS. SMTPS is port 465, but deprecated. For authenticated users, better use Port 587, Submission, with STARTTLS enforced.